# Browse https://dl.google.com using wget

Tags: wget

Is there any way to browse the https://dl.google.com using `wget`?

Ex - I have this link https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r30.0.5-linux.zip and I want to list all the contents in https://dl.google.com/android/repository. Is it possible?

Comment: *"I want to list all the contents in https://dl.google.com/android/repository. Is it possible?"* -- only if the web server allowed it (i.e. assuming the server generated an `.html` directory listing for you).